# Will spring RestTemplate checks certificate revocation status

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Could you please let me know by default whether the spring `RestTemplate` do certificate revocation status check? If yes, which one it does CRL or OCSP? or If I do the JVM settings it will take as per the JVM settings.

I am not able to find it from any documentation.

I use spring-boot 1.3.5

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to answer cause [RestTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) is using a [ClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/ClientHttpRequestFactory.html) to create Requests which will then be executed. The default one which is being used is [SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory.html) that uses JDK internals and should let you manipulate its behavior by passing in JVM settings. I'm not aware of the details of the JVM but I think you can configure if it should check CRL, OCSP or both as well as some other things.

But if you are using a different one like [Netty4ClientHttppRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory.html), [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) or [OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/OkHttp3ClientHttpRequestFactory.html) the behavior might be different cause the implementation behind might be a different one. In these cases I suggest you have a look at the documentation of those projects.

Hope that helps.